# Problem with swiperjs installation in Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

When I install by npm Swiper in Angular, that is, I execute this command:

> npm install swiper

I have these issue:

> ERROR in node_modules/swiper/angular/angular/src/swiper-slide.directive.d.ts(6,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
> node_modules/swiper/angular/angular/src/swiper-slide.directive.d.ts(7,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
> node_modules/swiper/angular/angular/src/swiper-slide.directive.d.ts(10,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
> node_modules/swiper/angular/angular/src/swiper-slide.directive.d.ts(11,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
> node_modules/swiper/angular/angular/src/swiper.component.d.ts(123,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
> node_modules/swiper/angular/angular/src/swiper.component.d.ts(124,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
> node_modules/swiper/angular/angular/src/swiper.component.d.ts(127,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
> node_modules/swiper/angular/angular/src/swiper.component.d.ts(128,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
> node_modules/swiper/angular/angular/src/swiper.component.d.ts(131,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
> node_modules/swiper/angular/angular/src/swiper.component.d.ts(132,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
> node_modules/swiper/angular/angular/src/swiper.component.d.ts(135,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
> node_modules/swiper/angular/angular/src/swiper.component.d.ts(136,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
> node_modules/swiper/angular/angular/src/swiper.component.d.ts(138,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
> node_modules/swiper/angular/angular/src/swiper.component.d.ts(139,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
> node_modules/swiper/angular/angular/src/swiper.component.d.ts(217,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
> node_modules/swiper/angular/angular/src/swiper.component.d.ts(219,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
> node_modules/swiper/angular/angular/src/swiper.component.d.ts(221,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
> node_modules/swiper/angular/angular/src/swiper.component.d.ts(223,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
> node_modules/swiper/angular/angular/src/swiper.component.d.ts(231,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
> node_modules/swiper/angular/angular/src/swiper.component.d.ts(232,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
> node_modules/swiper/angular/angular/src/swiper.component.d.ts(240,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

I have installed the following Angular version package:

- Angular CLI: `7.1.2`
- Node: `12.18.3`
- OS: `win32 x64`
- Angular: `7.0.0`